# Scanf() increased after called another function

Tags: c, ubuntu, scanf

I want to create few interfaces. Hence, there is few functions for the interface as well.

My main code is as below :

```
int main (void)
{
    int choice;
    scanf("%d", &choice);
    while(choice != 99)
    {
        switch(choice)
        {
            case 1: title1(); break;
            case 2 : title2(); break;
            default : printf("Error");
        }
        scanf("%d", &choice);     <-- edit
    }
return 0;
}
```

As for the others functions :

```
void title1(void)
{
    int choice;
    scanf("%d", &choice);
    while(choice != 99)
    {
        switch(choice)
        {
            case 1: titleA(); break;
            case 2 : titleB(); break;
            default : printf("Error");
        }
        scanf("%d", &choice);     <-- edit
    }
main();
}
void title2()
{
    int choice;
    scanf("%d", &choice);
    while(choice != 99)
    {
        switch(choice)
        {
            case 1: titleC(); break;
            case 2 : titleD(); break;
            default : printf("Error");
        }
        scanf("%d", &choice);     <-- edit
    }
main();
}
```

The example of the input for the program is :

```
1   then    99    then    99
```

But the actual is :

```
1   then    99    then    99  then   99
```

which need an extra `99` to exit the program.

If I enter like this :

```
1   then    99    then    2    then    99
```

I need to input 3 times `99` to exit the program.

What is the problem with the `scanf`? How can I solve it?

SOLVED :

I change the `return 0;` in the main() to `exit(0);`, and it's work fine, but I'm not sure is it correct or not to do that.

Comment: What makes you think the problem is with `scanf()` rather than with the way your code is using `scanf()`? At the least, `scanf()` has been tested by a lot of people on a lot of programs without finding bugs in it. Your code, I fear, has not been tested by more than one person. It is one of the marks of a tyro that he blames his tools. @John3136 has diagnosed some of the issues. You probably don't want to be calling `main()` from in your functions; you return from the function (by 'falling of the end') and that gets you back to the function that called it. It's one reason you need the extra 99.

Comment: So, you meaning that I;m calling the `main()` is wrong? I should create another function for the initial interface?

Comment: In C, it is (occasionally) OK to call `main()`; it C++, it is verboten.  What you've got here does not look like a case where you should be calling `main()`.  You should be returning to `main()`, but you do that by executing the (conceptual) `return;` at the end of your `void title1(void) { ... /* return; */ }` function, not by calling `main()` again.

Comment: I changed the `return 0` in the main() to `exit(0)`, it's work fine. Is it correct?

Comment: It works fine. Personally, I like to see functions return, so I prefer the 'return 0;' at the end of `main`. The C89 standard requires that; the C99 standard sadly allows you to omit `return` from the end of `main()` and implicitly does `return 0;` — but that's a rule only for `main()`. I think that is an appalling rule and don't use it. If you're calling `main()` recursively, there's a difference between `return 0;` and `exit(0);` at the end of `main()`. The former does not necessarily terminate the program; the latter does. I'm not sure that's enough of an excuse to use `exit(0);`, though.

Comment: Thanks. Because I'm doing it for the menu of simple system call for Ubuntu, since I'm using Ubuntu, and I'm new in C Language, notice that much different between Java and HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Your `scanf()`s are outside the while loops where you use the value - (`choice` is not updated).
All your methods call `main()` - What the?

You probably want something more self contained like:

```
void title1(void)
{
    int choice=0;
    while(choice != 99)
    {
        scanf("%d", &choice);
        switch(choice)
        {
            case 1: titleA(); break;
            case 2: titleB(); break;
            default: printf("Error"); 
                     break
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oops... I forget that line, I edited it. I do had `scanf` inside the `while` loop. The problem is same. Meanwhile, I have follow your method, that assign choice to a value, but the result still the same.

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty simple. You could use a debugger to see what exactly is happening.

EDIT: Rewriting title1() for better clarity.

```
void title2()
{
    int choice;
    scanf("%d", &choice);
    while(choice != 99)
    {
        switch(choice)
        {
            case 1: titleC(); break;
            case 2 : titleD(); break;
            default : printf("Error");
        }
        scanf("%d", &choice);    
    }
    main();
    printf("About to return from title1()\n");//EDIT
    return;//EDIT
}
```

Lets consider the first input set.

```
1   then    99    then    99
```

In this case, `1` takes you inside `title1()`. and `99` brings you out of the `while` loop inside `title1()` and **there is a call to `main()` function again**. So you need to enter one more `99` to come out of the while loop in `main()` function. After you have come out of the `while` of `main()` control will return to `title1()` and "About to return from title1()" gets printed and then control returns to the `main()` function called by operating system. In the `main()` function you need to enter one more `99` to come out of the loop and exit the program.

Call stack looks like

```
--------------
    main()
   --------
    title1()
   --------
    main()
--------------
```

To exit each function you need to enter one `99`.

I strongly suggest you use a debugger like [GDB](http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) to walk through your program and figure out what exactly is happening.

Comment: When the program run, input `1` to enter title1(), and input `99` to exit title1(). Now I should in main(), so input `99` to exit the program, but it's not working, I need an extra `99` to exit the program, meaning that I need three times `99` to exit the program.

Comment: As i mentioned earlier, main() is called twice. 1st the operating system calls main() function. And then title1() calls main. Program can only exit when the main() called by the operating system returns. Which happens when you type the second 99.

Comment: @AnonyNewbie Did you understand the code flow ? I suggest you to write a different interface instead of using main(). Also use 'do while' loops instead of while loops. That makes the code simpler.

Comment: I understand the my code flow, just notice that it's different with others language, like the Java, PHP and javascript. Now I create the interface with `void` function, so it's safer than calling function with return value. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

I think it may help you.....i m trying to explain how your code is flowing....

when u start or execute your program it enters first in the main() function as defined->

```
int main (void)
{
    int choice;
    scanf("%d", &choice);
    while(choice != 99)
    {
        switch(choice)
        {
            case 1: title1(); break;
            case 2 : title2(); break;
            default : printf("Error");
        }
        scanf("%d", &choice);     <-- edit
    }
return 0;
}
```

so u need to enter the data for choice & u entered it as 1 so while(choice !=99) becomes true & it switches to title1() **but main thing happens here.... as u enter in title() u have defined another int choice and it is local to this function so u enter again the value as 99  & it is stored in this variable because it is local. Now its while(choice != 99) becomes false so now again it calls main() & again in this call main declares int choice which also needs value to be entered again so u enters again 99 then its while(choice != 99) becomes false & then it calls return 0; & program exits.**

Comment: Did you mean that the `choice` cannot repeatly used throughout the program?

Comment: i m trying to say that if u define a variable with same name inside another function then when u try to use that variable in that function u are accessing it's local variable. so when u enter in title1() function u defined the variable named choice again so now it will be used when u try to access the variable choice but once u are out of this function this variable is removed so now u are in main so u can access its declared variable **choice**. Try to read about local & global variable.